# Trying to implement the equivalent of "insert image into post" in a rails 3 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, forms

Coming from the world of PHP and Wordpress, I am trying to implement a form where, I upload a bunch of images attached to a post. However, I want to insert images within the body of the post.

The flow should be:

1. Fill out the form fields
2. Upload images.
3. The image field should have the option of been inserted into the post body.
4. On hitting submit, the controller should save the form with the images embedded in the post body.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: How well do you know Rails? What prior experience do you have in PHP and Rails?

Comment: Hi Devin, Sorry for not giving too much background: I have an app implemented in Rails 3.1 in that, I have 3 models: Post, Category and Attachment. In the current implementation, my form view accepts attributes for Post and Attachment as well as Category(nested model). However I want to mimic Wordpress's "Insert into Post" functionality for my Attachment.

Comment: Ah, it should be easy. All you would need is some javascript that can handle a new upload then insert that new resources URL into the post.

Comment: Thanks Devin, I use paperclip currently and I have to hit submit for the pictures to completely upload. You think I can get this resource URL without reloading the page?

Comment: Well yeah you can AJAX forms in Rails like you would with any other web framework. http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow would be simple to implement, I would tackle resource uploads inside a separate controller since you may want to extend it later and you don't want the upload logic cluttering up your Posts controller. You can use some of the great gems Ruby has for images uploads like:

- CarrierWave ([Website](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)) ([Rdoc](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/)) ([Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/carrierwave))
- Paperclip ([Website](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip))  ([Rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/frames)) ([Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/paperclip))

Once you have image uploads working you can move on to integrating it with your Posts. Set up a relationship between your Uploads controller and the Posts controller. I would use a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) relationship which would enable you to record what images are used in what posts.

Then the only thing that's left is to create a form on your Posts create page for uploading images. There are many ways to do this but I would start out with a simple static form as a proof of concept in the beginning and then [move into using AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) ([text version](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast)) and some JavaScript to make the upload form more user friendly.

Once you have that working there are other modifications you can make including adding support for a layout engine like Markdown or Textile which would make adding style to Posts easier and potentially have better support for adding images into a post body.

Anyway, these are just high level concepts and I hope that they are enough to point you in the right direction. If you need help with the basics feel free to search StackOverflow and you can find similar questions or if you need additional clarification you may comment on this post.